# Most elegant way to summarize data at different levels using ARRAY_AGG() AND SUM()?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to summarize `count` at the `id` level. For each `id` summary row, I also want an ARRAY of STRUCTs field which summarizes the data for each of two attributes: `a1` and `a2`.

Here is how I managed to do it, with 4 queries and 6 `SELECT` statements, but I'm thinking there must be a more streamlined way to do this.

1) For each of the attribute summary, doing the `ARRAY_AGG()` in an outer query after doing the `SUM()` seems like it could be done in one step, although one cannot put a `SUM()` within and `ARRAY_AGG()`.

2) Doing each of the summaries, first on the `id` and then on each attribute and then joining all of these also seems like it should be done in a single step.

Note that I do value the readability of this query. But I'm thinking there must be some readable "shorthands" I'm missing here.

````
WITH data AS
((SELECT "A" as id, 1 as count, "a" as a1, "d" as a2)
UNION ALL (SELECT "A", 2, "a", "e")
UNION ALL (SELECT "A", 3, "b", "d")
UNION ALL (SELECT "A", 4, "a", "d")
UNION ALL (SELECT "B", 2, "a", "e")
UNION ALL (SELECT "B", 3, "b", "e")
UNION ALL (SELECT "B", 4, "a", "d")
),

#Summarize on id
datasummary as (
SELECT 
  data.id, SUM(data.count) as total
FROM 
  data
GROUP BY 
  id),

#Summarize in TWO STEPS for a1.  There must be a way to do this in one step?
data2summary as (
SELECT 
  id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a1, count)) as a1
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    id, a1, SUM(count) as count
  FROM 
    data
  GROUP BY 
    id, a1)
GROUP BY id),


#Summarize in TWO STEPS for a2.  There must be a way to do this in one step?
data3summary as (
SELECT 
  id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a2, count)) as a2
FROM 
  (SELECT 
     id, a2, SUM(count) as count
   FROM 
     data
   GROUP BY 
     id, a2)
GROUP BY 
  id)

#Join everything in one table
SELECT 
  t.id,  t.total, t2.a1, t3.a2
FROM 
  datasummary t 
    LEFT JOIN data2summary t2 ON t.id = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN data3summary t3 ON t.id = t3.id```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I'm thinking there must be some readable "shorthands" I'm missing here.

Below produces the very same result that your original query, while still quite readable, simple (and sexy I think)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION x(a ANY TYPE) AS (
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT val, SUM(`count`) `count` FROM UNNEST(a) GROUP BY val)
);
SELECT id, SUM(`count`) AS total,
  x(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a1 AS val, `count`))) a1, 
  x(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a2 AS val, `count`))) a2
FROM data
GROUP BY id
```

You can test, play with above using your dummy data as n below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION x(a ANY TYPE) AS (
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT val, SUM(`count`) `count` FROM UNNEST(a) GROUP BY val)
);
WITH data AS (
  SELECT "A" AS id, 1 AS `count`, "a" AS a1, "d" AS a2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT "A", 2, "a", "e" UNION ALL 
  SELECT "A", 3, "b", "d" UNION ALL 
  SELECT "A", 4, "a", "d" UNION ALL 
  SELECT "B", 2, "a", "e" UNION ALL 
  SELECT "B", 3, "b", "e" UNION ALL 
  SELECT "B", 4, "a", "d" 
)
SELECT id, SUM(`count`) AS total,
  x(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a1 AS val, `count`))) a1, 
  x(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a2 AS val, `count`))) a2
FROM data
GROUP BY id
```

with result

[image]

Comment: #StandardSQL poetry!

Comment: yea, that 's what I meant by `sexy` - you found better wording for this :o)

Answer (score 0):

This one's a bit odd, because you're intentionally creating independent repetitions for the a1 and a2 groupings. The implication here is any analysis of a1 doesn't care about a2 and vice versa, as they can't be recombined once you've lost the relationship information between the two values.

If you do need to correlate using the combinations of a1 and a2 values, consider keeping the combinations together in your struct rather building two independent arrays.  You can also compute the per-id totals at the same time:

```
SELECT
 id,
 SUM(subtotal) as total,
 ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a1, a2, subtotal)) as partial_sums
FROM
(
SELECT
  id,
  a1,
  a2,
  SUM(count) as subtotal
FROM data
GROUP BY id, a1, a2
)
GROUP BY id
```

Assuming you persist the partial summaries as a table, you can expand the partial summaries later to compute either the a1-only or a2-only breakdowns.  The following example uses ANY_VALUE for projecting the total because all rows share the same value and avoid an additional GROUP BY.  The building of the array using the outer query may be entirely unnecessary for the use case, however.

```
SELECT
   id,
   ANY_VALUE(total) as total,
   ARRAY_AGG(a1_summary) as a1_partial_sums
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id,
    total,
    STRUCT(p.a1, SUM(p.subtotal)) as a1_summary
  FROM
   `partial_summary_table`
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(partial_sums) as p
  GROUP BY id, total, p.a1
)
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: They are independent and in my use case I have many attributes so if I build all combinations, the table just does not summarize much.